# How to get debug postfix in executable name

Tags: cmake

I am using cmake 2.8.12.2. I have set `CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX`, and it is automatically used with the `add_library` command. But it is not automatically used with `add_executable` command. I have discovered that I can set the `DEBUG_POSTFIX` target property to get a debug postfix into the executable name, but this requires using an additional command.

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES DEBUG_POSTFIX ${CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX})
```

Is the second command explicitly setting the `DEBUG_POSTFIX` target property required or is there an easier way?

Comment: Your variable names are confusing me:  `PROJECT_NAME` is a bad name for a target, and `CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX` should contain the postfix you want to add. Why do you use a variable? Type it in as a string, at least if you are only using one. And don't use variable names starting with CMAKE_ as it is reserved for CMake's own variables. Or are you mistaken and you think this variable is what you need to pass? Then: You have to pass the postfix you want to add to the debug target.

Comment: I use a variable for every target and I have done so for a long long time on many projects.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The current cmake documentation for [set_target_properties](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/set_target_properties.html?highlight=set_target_properties) states

> There is also a `<CONFIG>_OUTPUT_NAME` that can set the output name on a per-configuration basis. `<CONFIG>_POSTFIX` sets a postfix for the real name of the target when it is built under the configuration named by  (in upper-case, such as “DEBUG_POSTFIX”). The value of this property is initialized when the target is created to the value of the variable `CMAKE_<CONFIG>_POSTFIX` (except for executable targets because earlier CMake versions which did not use this variable for executables).

So it seems to highlight the fact that cmake does not use the value of `CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX` in the name of executables. Therefore

```
add_executable(myexe ${SOURCE_FILES})
set_target_properties(myexe PROPERTIES DEBUG_POSTFIX ${CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX})
```

will use the value of the global variable `${CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX}` when building the `myexe` target for the `DEBUG` configuration.

Note that one of the commenters to this question was confused by the use of the variable `${PROJECT_NAME}`. This variable is automatically set to `myexe` when using `project(myexe)`. Using `${PROJECT_NAME}` is equivalent to `myexe` and it makes it easier to copy/paste to new CMakeLists.txt.

Answer (score 3):

Just to mention that, if you have in your project many sub-executables, it is worth having a look on [CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX.html). The variable in this case would need to be changed when running CMake for a specific build (Release/Debug), but this suffix is auto-attached to every ADD_EXECUTABLE(...)-call executable name. Tested and verified with CMake 2.8.12.2 and 3.0.2